# Qt QApplication framerate drop when maximizing window

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qapplication, qtopengl

We are using Qt for a visualization engine viewer, and we are having issues with the `QApplication::processEvents()` method.
Since we needed to control the framerate (in a game loop fashion), we overrided the QApplication to define our own and our game loop that looks like

```
MainApplication app;
// Some code here
while (true) {
    app.processEvents();
    app.doFrame();
    // sync code, nothing for now
}
```

This works fine, timing are about 0.001s for the `processEvents()` call, while, for an empty scene, the `doFrame()` takes about 0.0001s.
Now, we have a problem when we double click on title bar (to maximize the window). Indeed, after doing that, `processEvents()` call, goes from about 0.001s to about 0.01s (*10). Most of the time seems to be taken in `QPlatformBackingStore::composeAndFlush()`

The viewer used is based on QOpenGLWidget, and all the rendering is done outside of Qt (we are writing in the Qt FBO).

Please note that we are not overriding `QApplication::processEvents()`.

Thanks

Comment: The example is based on an incorrect assumption that the spin rate is stable to some degree which is wrong.